# Set MFC dialog form caption

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I need to set dialog form caption. I was trying to create CString variable that might be binded to caption with Class Wizard. But there is no main form control in selection menu. What is the way of doing that?

This is my dialog form:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MyDlg.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"


// MyDlg dialog

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(MyDlg, CDialog)

MyDlg::MyDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(MyDlg::IDD, pParent)
    , m_edit(_T(""))
{

}

MyDlg::~MyDlg()
{
}

void MyDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT1, m_edit);
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(MyDlg, CDialog)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDOK, &MyDlg::OnBnClickedOk)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// MyDlg message handlers


void MyDlg::OnBnClickedOk()
{

    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    CDialog::OnOK();
    txt=m_edit;
}
```

This is code that creates dialog:

```
BOOL CPreparationApp::InitInstance()
{

    MyDlg Dlg;
//how to tell Dlg to have form caption "BLABLABLA"?
    Dlg.DoModal();


        return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hoping I've understood your question in the right way:

```
// MyDlg.h
class MyDlg
{
 public:    // private is fine too if you're OOP nazi but you have to provide a SetDlgCaption method then.
    CString m_strDlgCaption;
};

// MyDlg.cpp
BOOL MyDlg::OnInitDialog( )
{
    SetWindowText( m_strDlgCaption );
}


BOOL CPreparationApp::InitInstance()
{

    MyDlg Dlg;

    Dlg.m_strDlgCaption = _T("A fancy caption for your dialog");
    Dlg.DoModal();
}
```

Comment: Something like Dlg.SetWindowText("BLABLABLA"); ? This code raises exception

Comment: You have to do it when you are certain that your window exists. As @ScottMcP-MVP suggest, you can put it in OnInitDialog. If you know in advance what your caption will be, put a CString member variable and a Set method to fill it, call the method between MyDlg dlg; and dlg.DoModal(); and in your OnInitDialog you can call SetWindowText( m_yourMemberVariable );

Answer (score 0):

If you have not already done it you first need to add an override in the dialog class for OnInitDialog. This is the first place you can execute code after the dialog and its control windows exist. You can put SetWindowText(_T("BLABLABLA")) in OnInitDialog to set the dialog caption.